# How to make call conferencing of two calls?

Tags: android

i have tried many things but not getting how to  do conferencing in android.
i can receive incoming call and make another outgoing call...but not able to combine those calls as "menu option merge do"...
if i can take object reference of phone or call class(internal class of android) i can  use conference method available theres

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no API for this in the Android SDK, sorry.